# Performance issues with appendTo() to create tables dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

After debugging my tables seemed to load slow (I assumed it was my server), I found that it was actually the front-end javascript, not the backend PHP. The server is responding in 3-4ms while the javascript handling is taking up to 350ms.

After reading [this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly), I found the culprit:

Article snippet:

```
var arr = reallyLongArray;
$.each(arr, function(count, item) {
    var newTd = $('<td></td>').html(item).attr('name','pieTD');
    var newTr = $('<tr></tr>');
    newTr.append(newTd);
    $('table').append(newTr);
});
```

The difference is I am using `appendTo()` instead of `append`. This is because my rows have dynamic jquery elements to them  - click handlers, `.data()`, etc.

The solution in the article is basically to concatenate your rows and then run **one** `.append()` at the end instead of one for each row.

Is there a similar solution for `appendTo()`? Perhaps appending to some sort of *ghost element* and then inserting the whole element at the end? Would this increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps appending to some sort of ghost element and then inserting the whole element at the end?

Exactly. You can create your rows and append them to a disconnected `tbody` element, then append that `tbody` element to your table. That way there's a *single* live DOM manipulation, not hundreds of them.

Comment: Would I still use `appendTo` with every iteration? The click handlers and other dynamic elements have failed in every attempt to take `appendTo` out of the loop clause. An example would be great :)

Comment: @hellohellosharp: Yes, you'd just use the `tbody` element instead of whatever you're using as the current target of `appendTo`. It would **really** help people answer if you'd show *your* code rather than code from an article.